# Clean up "open with app" settings in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I had installed an app, which registers as URL handler in Chrome. That means that Chrome is asking me if I want to open a specific URL in the desktop app instead of Chrome itself:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome dialog to open a URL in miroapp.]

I don't use that app anymore and have uninstalled it from my PC. unfortunately, Chrome still asks me every time if I want to open this with the (non-existing) app.

I haven't found any Chrome setting to remove this link. How can I clean this up?

Comment: Check your extensions at `chrome://extensions/`.

Comment: There's no extension for that app. It's a URL handler which is not listed in the extensions page.

Comment: Do you see anything pertinent in the registry at `HKCU\Software\Classes\Chrome`? Or (more likely) an entry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` whose name is similar to that of the app? Or just search the app's `.exe` file under it.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc, `HKCR\miroapp` existed and registered "URL:miroapp". ONce I deleted it, Chrome does not bug me anymore. Do you want to post that as an answer? I'm happy to accept it then.

Comment: Happy to help. I have added an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL protocols exist in the registry as sub-keys to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

For the poster, the key was `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\miroapp`.
Deleting the key has solved the problem and Chrome no longer
ask to open these URLs in the desktop app instead of Chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question specifically might be a bit off as, in my case, I was attempting to make the same type of change while still having the program installed (aka I'm not 100% sure how this might work with something that's been uninstalled), but this post did lead me to a much easier solution than messing with the registry, so I thought I would share it here:

Under "Apps" in the windows settings, you'll find "Default Apps" in the sidebar. At the bottom of that window are several options:

- Choose default apps by file type
- Choose default apps by protocol
- Set defaults by app

These options should cover everything someone might need in this type of situation. "Choose default apps by protocol" allowed me to change what program the specific URL I was looking for was associated with.